# errno -4048 on npm install in Angular project

Tags: angular, npm, npm-install

I have an Angular project that I will do a few changes for a client, when I try to run npm install I got this error:

```
npm ERR! path D:\myClientProject\node_modules\.staging\material-design-icons-f132a428\av\1x_web\ic_music_video_white_36dp.png
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! syscall unlink
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'D:\myClientProject\node_modules\.staging\material-design-icons-f132a428\av\1x_web\ic_music_video_white_36dp.png'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'D:\myClientProject\node_modules\.staging\material-design-icons-f132a428\av\1x_web\ic_music_video_white_36dp.png']
npm ERR!   cause:
npm ERR!    { Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'D:\myClientProject\node_modules\.staging\material-design-icons-f132a428\av\1x_web\ic_music_video_white_36dp.png'
npm ERR!      errno: -4048,
npm ERR!      code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!      syscall: 'unlink',
npm ERR!      path:
npm ERR!       'D:\\myClientProject\\node_modules\\.staging\\material-design-icons-f132a428\\av\\1x_web\\ic_music_video_white_36dp.png' },
npm ERR!   stack:
npm ERR!    'Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink \'D:\\myClientProject\\node_modules\\.staging\\material-design-icons-f132a428\\av\\1x_web\\ic_music_video_white_36dp.png\'',
npm ERR!   errno: -4048,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'unlink',
npm ERR!   path:
npm ERR!    'D:\\myClientProject\\node_modules\\.staging\\material-design-icons-f132a428\\av\\1x_web\\ic_music_video_white_36dp.png',
npm ERR!   parent: 'emaua-front' }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It's possible that the file was already in use (by a text editor or antivirus),
npm ERR! or that you lack permissions to access it.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator (though this is not recommended).
```

I've tried a few things already, but with no success:

- Run the command with cmd as Administrator
- Give all permissions in the project's folder
- Delete package-lock.json
- Restart the computer
- Deleted npm and npm-cache folder

Node version: 10.15.3

NPM version: 6.4.1

Have anyone faced this error?

Comment: did you tried to update npm  to the latest version  : `npm i -g npm` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try installing the latest *npm* version **v6.9.0** as of 18 April 2019.

```
npm i -g npm
```

This has solve my issue several times.